# Xenserver and linux lvm

Tags: ubuntu, lvm, xenserver

I need help regarding linux lvm on xenserver.
The linux vm have 3 disk assigned from xenserver.
After power outages the one disk get corrupted and linux vm wont boot.
Lvm report that cant find disk.
Is there any chance to extract data from that vm?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the storage in xenserver, and is it attached correctly to the VM ? If the answer is yes, then you might have to restore from a backup.